# Call method inside multiple tasks C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I am having a problem calling a method in a list of Tasks. I have a method that creates N number of tasks. In each task I perform some operations that in the end results an fetching data via `HttpWebRequest` and writing that data into a file. I use lock objects to lock the access to shared resources like variables. Everything performs great except the call for a method that creates a executes an `HttpWebRequest` (method `GetData`). Whenever I don't lock that call for the method (`GetData`) it seems that some data/files are skipped. For example:

- With the lock object I get file 1,2,3 and 4
- Without the lock object I get file 2,4 and 3

Here's the code for the method that creates the tasks

```
private object lockObjectWebRequest= new object();
private object lockObjectTransactions = new object();

public List<Task> ExtractLoanTransactionsData(string URLReceived, string Headers, string Body)
{
    List<Task> Tasks = new List<Task>();

    try
    {
        int Limit = 0;
        int OffsetItemsTotal = 0;
        int NumberOftasks = 4;

        // Create the task to run in parallel
        for (int i = 0; i <= NumberOftasks; i++)
        {
            int OffsetCalculated = 0;

            if (i > 0)
            {
                OffsetCalculated = Limit * i;
            }

            Tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                string URL = URLReceived+ "&offset=" + OffsetCalculated .ToString() + "&limit=" + Limit.ToString();
                string Output = string.Empty;

                lock (lockObjectWebRequest)
                {
                    Output = GetData(URL, Headers,Body);
                }

                if (Output != "[]")
                {
                    lock (lockObjectTransactions)
                    {

                        Identifier++;
                        Job.Identifier = Identifier;

                        // write to file
                        string json = JValue.Parse(Output).ToString(Formatting.Indented);

                        string FileName = OffSet.ToString() + Identifier;
                        string Path = @"C:\FileFolder\" + FileName + ".json";

                        File.WriteAllText(Path, json);
                    }
                }

            }));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Tasks = new List<Task>();
    }

    return Tasks;
}
```

Here's the code that performs the `HttpWebRequest`:

```
public string GetData(string URL, string Headers, string Body)
{
    string Data = string.Empty;
    Headers = Headers.Trim('{').Trim('}');
    string[] HeadersSplit = Headers.Split(new char[] { ',', ':' });

    HttpWebRequest WebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
    WebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential();
    WebRequest.Method = "POST";

    HttpWebResponse WebResponse;

    // Set necessary Request Headers
    for (int i = 0; i < HeadersSplit.Length; i = i + 2)
    {
        string HeaderPart1 = HeadersSplit[i].Replace("\"", "").Trim();
        string HeaderPart2 = HeadersSplit[i + 1].Replace("\"", "").Trim();

        if (HeaderPart1 == "Content-Type")
        {
            WebRequest.ContentType = HeaderPart2;
        }
        else if (HeaderPart1 == "Accept")
        {
            WebRequest.Accept = HeaderPart2;
        }
        else if (HeaderPart1 == "Authorization")
        {
            WebRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = HeaderPart2;
        }
    }

    WebRequest.Headers.Add("cache-control", "no-cache");

    // Add body to Request
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(WebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(Body);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        streamWriter.Close();
    }

     // Execute Request
     WebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)WebRequest.GetResponse();

     // Validate Response
     if (WebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
     {
         using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(WebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
         {
             Data = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
         }
      }

     return Data;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? The method doesn't have global data that is shared between tasks.

Comment: To start with please never ever ever ever write `catch (Exception ex)`. It's a bad anti-pattern. You should only ever catch specific exceptions that your can meaningfully handle. You should always code defensively to avoid exceptions in the first place.

Comment: There is quite a lot of code in your question. Ideally you should try to remove any line that is not related to the problem, and leave the absolute minimum that is still enough to reproduce the problem. This would make your question easier to answer.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I thought that would be easier to show all the code to see the flow. I also included the code of the method GetData because it seems that the problem happens when I call this method all all tasks created without a lockobject.

Comment: @AtomicBrownie - It's not easier to see more than is necessary. If you have to put a `lock` inside the task seems entirely wrong. Locking over all of that IO is insane. You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Enigmativity I change the code to have a minimal reproducible example like you said. Why is it wrong to have a lock inside the task? That was the way that I saw it be done to handle shared resources access. I also saw the use of SemaphoreSlim but I wast using async and await.

Comment: I can't see something obvious in your code that could explain the skipped files. I would like to express two suggestion though. 1) Remove the try/catch block. In case that an exception occurs in the `ExtractLoanTransactionsData` method, let the caller handle the exception. 2) Follow the [official naming guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions) and capitalization conventions. Using PascalCasing for local variables makes me (and possibly other readers) being continuously alerted while reading your code.

Comment: @AtomicBrownie - When you do a `Task.Factory.StartNew` you are saying that you want to run code in parallel. When you do a `lock` you are saying you want to NOT run some code in parallel. Combing the two is a bit counter-productive. Ideally you want to finish all of non-parallel code and then let the task go whoopie. Try not to mix them.

Comment: Maarten's answer is what I'd suggest to you. It should enable you to remove all the locks. I can't see any other shared resource that you need to lock over. That said you have variables in your code that aren't defined. I can not copy, paste, and compile your code. So I can't tell if something else is going on. Can you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @Enigmativity Maarten's answer is helping me remove the locks on the Identifier increment code, which I thank him for but not solving the problem of the files. I think the problem is in the code of the Http request at the GetData method. If I call that method without the lock it seems that I lose data ou by other words some Requests overlap each other in which results in the problem of getting only 3 files instead of 5 for example. Can that happen? Because nothing in the method GetData is shared between tasks.

Comment: @AtomicBrownie - It appears when you reduced done your code you removed some of the shared variables that you passed to `GetData`. You need to post a [mcve]. I keep stressing that and you seem to keep ignoring the request. Please post the code required to replicate your issue so that I can copy, paste, and compile your code.

Comment: @Enigmativity Sorry, I wasn't ignoring on purpose, I left myself get carried away in the questions. I removed one variable that is shared by accident. But I can't provide the API details for all of you to make the requests needed because the data retrieved from the API is confidential. I know I am not giving much space to work with but that is all that I can give. From my perspective and analysis the problem, as I have said, relies on the Request to the API. It seems that the requests overlap each other. I just wanted to understand the why of it and if is is even possible for that to happen.

Comment: @AtomicBrownie - you don't need to provide credentials, just a [mcve]. You can provide mock input and let us go from there. It really just needs to be something that you can run with real adata and that is compilable for us to work with it.

Answer (score 1):

But you do have data that is shared between the tasks: the local varible`Identifier` and the method argument `Job`.

You are writing to a file using the `Identifier` in the file-name. If the lock is not in place, that piece of code will be running simultaniously.

The implications for `Job` can't be deduced from your question.

I think you can solve the identifier problem by doing this:

```
var identifier = Interlocked.Increment(ref Identifier);
Job.Identifier = identifier; // Use 'identifier', not 'Identifier'

// write to file
string json = ...;

string FileName = OffSet.ToString() + "_" +
                  "MAMBU_LT_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + "_" +
                  identifier; // Use 'identifier', not 'Identifier'
...
```

Comment: That variable identifier increment and the file name construction is under a different lock object. The problem rises when I remove the lock object lockObjectAccounts that locks the call to the method GetData. Or is the lock object I am using not locking that variable increment?